# What is security: firewall: pattern:?

Tags: php, symfony

Because there is no info in documentation, maybe somebody here know what is pattern in security.yml:

```
security:
    firewall:
        pattern: .*
```

It`s a global pattern, that turn on this firewall? So when i use pattern: /directory, firewall will work only on that directory and there will be no security on /otherdirectory ?

Its confusing because there is pattern for firewall and still i have to use:

```
access_control:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this defines which directories are "protected" by firewall. This, however, does not mean protected as locked out because that part is covered by `access_control`. Basically, if you URL hits the firewall only then it checks for roles.

`Symfony2` makes quite a distinction between **Authentication** and **Authorization**.  Your firewall will ensure the user was **authenticated** (correct login) and `access_control` will ensure that user was **authorized** (sufficient rights - roles). Those two term cannot part separate ways and authorization goes **always** after authentication.

Comment: Thank You. Im new with symfony so it`s good to know. Authentication works strange for me now :) For example: Im not authenticated, then i login -> Im authenticated -> Logout -> Im authenticated as anonymous.

Comment: You're welcome! :) "Im not authenticated" never happens except if you're outside of firewall. Otherwise, you're **always** authenticated either as `anonymous` or concrete user.